# Google Colab or DataBricks Notebook using R does not display BupaR

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, databricks, process-mining

I used to perform process mining using R into R Studio or using PowerBI from Custom Visual (R). Process Mining is performed using bupaR and processanimateR libraries.

For some reason running the same code (only data access is differs) into Google Colab or Azure DataBricks Notebook using R does not expose the process_map or process_animate objects.

Code for loading libraries:

```
%r
require(devtools)
install_version(
  package = "edeaR",
  repos   = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
)
install_version(
  package = "bupaR",
  repos   = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
)
install_version(
  package = "processanimateR",
  repos   = "http://cran.us.r-project.org"
)
```

Code for loading data:

```
%r
library(SparkR)
df_rr_sp = tableToDF("default.jira") # library(SparkR)
df_rr_rr = collect(df_rr_sp)
```

Code for making eventlog:

```
%r
library(bupaR)
e <- eventlog(dataset, # library('edeaR')
                activity_id = ".activity_id",
                case_id = ".case_id",
                resource_id = ".resource_id",
                activity_instance_id = ".activity_instance_id",
                lifecycle_id = ".lifecycle_id",
                timestamp =  ".timestamp_changed"
            )
```

Process Map:

```
%r
library(bupaR)
process_map(e,
                type_nodes = frequency("absolute"),
                type_edges = performance(units="hours"),
                sec_nodes = frequency("absolute"),
                sec_edges = performance(FUN = max, units ="days"),
                rankdir = "TB", 
                render = TRUE, 
                controlIconsEnabled = T,
                panEnabled = 
            )
```

Animate Map:

```
library(processanimateR)
animate_process(e)
```

Then I tried some sample dataset to check:

```
library(eventdataR)
library(bupaR)
data(patients)
process_map(patients, render=T)
```

Seems that I am experiencing same issue even by using a sample dataset, so something is happening with Databricks interpreter?
Then I tested the same on Google Colab using R runtime and the same thing is happening there.

Any idea?